# Python: List is replaced by the new list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got a question regarding list within python. I use the append method to actually append values to my list, now it only replaced the list with new values.

This is my code:

```
def init(serial):
    serial_number = serial
    api_call = "http://wwww.herecomesmyhyperlink/"+serial_number    
    result = []
    with open('allserials.csv') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='|')
        for row in reader:
            if row[0].strip() == api_call:
                result.append(row[1].strip())

    call_api(serial_number,result)
    return

def call_api(get_serial,get_result):
    list_serial = []

    for i in range(len(get_result)):
        # do an api call
        ....
        # get result of api call
        list_serial.append(api_result)

    sort_serials(list_serial)
    return

def sort_serials(get_list_serial)
    sorted_list_serial = sorted(get_list_serial, reverse=True)
    print(sorted_list_serial)
    max_results = 10
    length_of_sorted_list_serial = len(get_list_serial)

    if length_of_sorted_list_serial < max_results:
        get_first_list_element = sorted_list_serial[0]
        get_second_element_of_that_list = get_first_list_element[1]
        init(get_second_element_of_that_list)
    else:
        print("it is not smaller")
    return

print(init('1320739'))
```

`sorted_list_serial` would contain something like: `[rankingid,serial,title]`.

`get_second_element_of_that_list`: `[serial]`

The thing is that when I run my code I got the following results:

```
s: 1320739,      max result:10       length of the list:3
s: 1523039,      max result:10       length of the list:9
```

What the code does is that instead of having a list of 12 items, it replace the list with the 3 items with the new list of 9 items.

What I want is to actually have a new list containing 12 items, so that the first 3 items are  still within the list and the 9 other elements are added to the original list.

Comment: Does the API return a list?

Comment: It gives me a JSON response which I store, with other information, in a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list is scoped to the function `call_api()` so pull it out, or pass it to each function, or create a class.

```
def init(serial):
    serial_number = serial

    result = []
    with open('allserials.csv') as csvfile:
      result.append()


    return result

def call_api(get_serial,get_result):
    # list_serial = []
    #
    # Move this out
    # Or pass it along to each function

    for i in range(len(get_result)):
        # do an api call
        ....
        # get result of api call
        list_serial.append(api_result)


    return list_serial

def sort_serials(get_list_serial)
    sorted_list_serial = sorted(get_list_serial, reverse=True)

    max_results = 10
    length_of_sorted_list_serial = len(get_list_serial)

    if length_of_sorted_list_serial < max_results:
        get_first_list_element = sorted_list_serial[0]
        get_second_element_of_that_list = get_first_list_element[1]

    else:
        print("it is not smaller")
    return {'get_second_element_of_that_list':get_second_element_of_that_list, 'sorted_serial_list':sorted_serial_list}
```

So scope it to the same function, and have the other functions return results:

```
def run():
    list_serial = []
    serial_number = '1320739'
    result = init(serial_number)
    # here the items get set
    list_serial = call_api(serial_number,result)
    # here they get sorted
    serial_sorted = sort_serials(list_serial)
    # list serial is now the sorted list
    list_serial = serial_sorted['sorted_serial_list']
    get_second_element_of_that_list = serial_sorted['get_second_element_of_that_list']

    init(get_second_element_of_that_list)
```

Or redefine how its passed:

```
    serial_number = '1320739'
    init(serial_number, list_serial)
    call_api(serial_number,result, list_serial)
    sort_serials(list_serial)

    init(get_second_element_of_that_list, list_serial)
```

Or just pull it out:

```
.
.
.
list_serial = []
print(init('1320739'))
```

Or create a class:

```
class SomeClassNameHere(object):
    def __init__(self,serialnumber=None, item2=''):
        self.serialnumber = serialnumber
        self.item3 = item2
        self.listserial = []
        self.run(item2)

    def doOtherStuff(self):
        # self.listserial will be updated
        self.listserial = [1,2,3]
        print(self.item3)
        print(self.serialnumber)

    def run(self,passeditem2):
        print('Item2 has been passed: {0}'.format(passeditem2))
        print('listserial not updated:',self.listserial)
        self.doOtherStuff()
        print('listserial updated:',self.listserial)



 here = SomeClassNameHere(serialnumber='456',item2='somestring')
 print(here.serialnumber)
 print(here.item3)
 here.run()
 here.doOtherStuff()
```

Comment: Depending on how many lines of code you are working with, it might be beneficial to put it all inside of a class as well. That way you would be able to get these pieces working, and it would be easier to access the items. I'll update my answer with one way to do it.

Comment: I tried to add an example of how the class would look.

Comment: Thanks! for now my code is not that big, but I will keep in mind to use a structure like you proposed. thanks for the help.